# C++ create & compile class

Tags: c++, class, compiler-errors

Hello people of stackoverflow,

I am a newby when it comes to C++. I tried to create a class but of course, I get error messages when I compile my program. I am here hoping some of you will tell me what is wrong with my program and what I'm doing wrong!

P.S. : I am using OpenFOAM, so some things differ such as the ".C" extension (instead of ".cpp") and the use of the Foam library.

**Vessels.H**

```
#ifndef Vessels_H
#define Vessels_H

// * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * //

class Vessels
{
public:

Vessels(double xCoordinate, double yCoordinate, double zCoordinate, double vesselLength, double vesselRadius, double P_outside, double P_inside);
int pointIndex();
double flowRate();
double wellModel();

private:

double m_xCoordinate, m_yCoordinate, m_zCoordinate, m_vesselLength, m_vesselRadius, m_P_outside, m_P_inside;
double flow, meshVolume, meshSize, equivalentRadius;
int index;

};

#include "Vessels.C"
#endif
```

**Vessels.C**

```
#include "Vessels.H"

// * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * //

// CONSTRUCTOR

Vessels::Vessels(double xCoordinate, double yCoordinate, double zCoordinate, double vesselLength, double vesselRadius, double P_outside, double P_inside) : m_xCoordinate(xCoordinate), m_yCoordinate(yCoordinate), m_zCoordinate(zCoordinate), m_vesselLength(vesselLength), m_vesselRadius(vesselRadius), m_P_outside(P_outside), m_P_inside(P_inside)
{

}

// METHODS 

// Corresponding index for point (xCoordinate,yCoordinate,zCoordinate)

int Vessels::pointIndex() 
{
    return mesh.findCell(point(m_xCoordinate,m_yCoordinate,m_zCoordinate));
}

// Calculation of flow rate in the vessel using the Hagen-Poiseuille equation

double Vessels::flowRate()
{
    return M_PI*Foam::pow(m_vesselRadius,4.0)/(8.0*mu.value*m_vesselLength)*(m_P_inside-m_P_outside);
}

// Numerical well model

double Vessels::wellModel()
{
    Vessels vessel(double xCoordinate, double yCoordinate, double zCoordinate, double vesselLength, double vesselRadius, double P_outside, double P_inside);
    index = vessel.pointIndex();
    flow = vessel.flowRate();
    meshVolume = mesh.V()[index];
    meshSize = Foam::pow(meshVolume,1.0/3);
    equivalentRadius = 3.0*meshSize/(3.0+2.0*M_PI*meshSize);

    m_P_inside = P[index] + mu.value*flow/(4.0*M_PI*K)*(1.0/equivalentRadius - 1.0/m_vesselRadius);
    return m_P_inside;
}
```

If it is of any interest for anyone, here are my compiler errors so far :

```
Vessels.C: In member function ‘double Vessels::flowRate()’:
Vessels.C:65:52: erreur: invalid operands of types ‘double’ and ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ to binary ‘operator*’
Vessels.C: In member function ‘double Vessels::wellModel()’:
Vessels.C:73:18: erreur: request for member ‘pointIndex’ in ‘vessel’, which is of non-class type ‘Vessels(double, double, double, double, double, double, double)’
Vessels.C:74:17: erreur: request for member ‘flowRate’ in ‘vessel’, which is of non-class type ‘Vessels(double, double, double, double, double, double, double)’
Vessels.C:79:35: erreur: invalid operands of types ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ and ‘double’ to binary ‘operator*’
Vessels.C: In member function ‘double Vessels::flowRate()’:
Vessels.C:66:1: attention : contrôle a atteint la fin non void de la fonction [-Wreturn-type]
```

thank you! and I am open to all advices possible in order to better understand how to use C++!

Comment: Why do you include Vessels.C in Vessels.h? Including Vessels.h in Vessels.C is correct but the other way around isn't right.

Comment: `mu.value` - What is it?

Comment: @legends2k because when I include Vessels.h in my main program then compile the main, it automatically compiles my class as well

Comment: @Farah.Yasmina, Read about separated compilation

Comment: @soon mu is the blood viscosity defined in another file as a dimensionedScalar..

Comment: You're missing parens at pow() on line 65, you should remove line 72 and `vessel.`

Comment: @Farah.Yasmina: Then it should be declared as an `extern`.

Comment: @soon I read about it and am planning on doing this once everything is working well...

Comment: @Farah.Yasmina, `value` is a member function? If not, show declaration of `mu`, please.

Comment: value is a function that extracts the value of a dimensioned scalar. In openFoam we can define variables along with their dimension and include the whole thing in a file called "transportProperties". So for mu I have : '    dimensionedScalar mu
    (
        transportProperties.lookup("mu")
    );'  and in transportProperties : 'mu        mu [ 1 -1 -1 0 0 0 0 ] 1e-05;' where [ 1 -1 -1 0 0 0 0 ] indicates its dimension

Comment: You haven't declared `mu` before using it, fix this first. I think you will need to `#include "file-where-mu-is-declared.h"`. And noone includes `.c` files inside header file (noone but you, of course), get rid of it.

Comment: @SpongeBobFan Most people who use OpenFOAM include a `.c` file inside the header file. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

```
Vessels vessel(double xCoordinate, double yCoordinate, double zCoordinate, double vesselLength, double vesselRadius, double P_outside, double P_inside);
```

This is a declaration of a function, not of an object. Looks like you want to create a copy of your object, but I see no reason for it. Just remove it.

```
double Vessels::wellModel()
{
    index = pointIndex();
    flow = flowRate();
    meshVolume = mesh.V()[index];
    meshSize = Foam::pow(meshVolume,1.0/3);
    equivalentRadius = 3.0*meshSize/(3.0+2.0*M_PI*meshSize);

    m_P_inside = P[index] + mu.value*flow/(4.0*M_PI*K)*(1.0/equivalentRadius - 1.0/m_vesselRadius);
    return m_P_inside;
}
```

---

> value is a function that extracts the value of a dimensioned scalar.

In this case, you forget a parentheses here:

```
return M_PI*Foam::pow(m_vesselRadius,4.0)/(8.0*mu.value()*m_vesselLength)*(m_P_inside-m_P_outside);
//                                                     ^^
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first error is in the line:

```
return M_PI*Foam::pow(m_vesselRadius,4.0)/(8.0*mu.value*m_vesselLength)*(m_P_inside-m_P_outside);
```

This line is way too long and complicated.

Split this line into four or five simple and readable lines.

Create intermediate variables and give them meaningful names.

Create a variable `double result = ...` in which you store the final result.

Call `pow` with one variable at each argument, not with calculations.

By doing so, you will at worst isolate your compile errors much better, and at best, maybe even fix some.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are making a function, not an object

> Vessels vessel(double xCoordinate, double yCoordinate, double zCoordinate, double vesselLength, double vesselRadius, double P_outside, double P_inside);